# Using URL shortening service

Tags: url-shortener

I am trying to use URL shortening service in my app. However, I want to expose my custom tinyURL domain rather than the one of the services. For this, I've done the following:

1. I shorten my long URLS from a stardard tinyURL service and get a shortened URL like - http://tinyurl.com/abcdXYZ
2. I expose the url as http:// kk.ly/abcdXYZ (Assuming kk.ly is the domain that I own)

I also do a CNAME forwarding from kk.ly to tinyurl.com

I wanted to know if there are any gotchas with this approach? Has anybody attempted this before - any experiences/learnings to be shared?

Thanks,
KK

Answer (score 1):

The CNAME means that the connection will be redirected to `tinyurl.com`, but the URL in the HTTP request will sill feature the `kk.ly` hostname rather than `tinyurl.com`. I do not know if the HTTP server at `tinyurl.com` will take offense. Also, the *people* managing `tinyurl.com` may themselves feel offended (basically, you are using their service without keeping their name in the URL). I suggest that you check beforehand.

Comment: In that case, are there any other URL shortening services that allow such an action? Its just that I do not want to take the overhead of maintaining my own URL-shortening service, but want to expose the tinyURLs on my own domain. I am sure someone would have faced similar problem in the past

Answer (score 1):

Just 'cause you can setup a cname and redirect traffic to tinyurl.com doesn't mean they'll actually service the requests.  Try taking a working tinyurl.com url and replacing the domain name with their IP address and you get a 404 error.  A custom cname would probably result in the same.

Google's Short Sites service specifically supports custom cnames, but it is only available for Google Apps.

http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-tinyurl-like-redirection-service/8333/

Comment: yeah u r right - tinyurl would not allow me to do that,. But are there any such services that would allow me? Anyone knows of such services?